# How to control scrollTop for HTML5 form validation?

Tags: html, forms, validation

I use simple HTML5 form validation for requiring inputs:

```
<input type="text" required>
```

However, there is a fixed header on a page and input with an error displays under the block.
Is there any way to control scrollTop for validation events on a whole site?

P.S. If the question sounds weird, please explain why. Thank you!

P.P.S. [Code sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaLeox)

Comment: Please provide a code snippet with a fixed header such that it hides the error.

Comment: @Alohci I've edited the question.

Comment: @Alohci I've provided link with working example, is it helpful?

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as with [anchors and position fixed](https://www.google.com/search?q=anchors%20and%20position%20fixed) ... so adapt one of those techniques maybe? (If that works in such a context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? Simple and quick but I don't know how efficient it is on mobile devices or tablets. If you want it to be more precise, use an array or store the window value and wait for on-change before you move it down a little bit.

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var win_scroll_y = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).scrollTop(win_scroll_y - 60); // Change to move closer to top or further
  },50)
})
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
header {
  position :fixed;
  top :0;
  right :0;
  left :0;
  background :green;
  width :100%;
  height :50px;
}
form{
  padding-top :50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <header></header>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" required value="first">
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <input type="text" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: I've even haven't considered in such a way. Thank you, that's pretty simple!

Comment: @Jarvis Your welcome! If this is for production use, make sure it looks nice and is responsive with every view-port, mobile, tablets and different resolution monitors.